# Declaring two or more "Integer variables" with the different names in the same line (expecting reply from Ruby Folks)

Tags: ruby, integer

I was trying to declare two or more variables in the same line. I tried:

```
aa = 100, bb = 200, cc = 300
```

in which `aa` shows, it's an `array`; `bb` and `cc` shows, they are `integesrs`. I'm adding here the output of IRB.

```
irb(main):023:0> aa = 100, bb = 200, cc = 300
=> [100, 200, 300]
irb(main):024:0> aa+bb
Traceback (most recent call last):
        5: from C:/Ruby27-x64/bin/irb.cmd:31:in `<main>'
        4: from C:/Ruby27-x64/bin/irb.cmd:31:in `load'
        3: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/irb-1.2.6/exe/irb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        2: from (irb):24
        1: from (irb):24:in `+'
TypeError (no implicit conversion of Integer into Array)
irb(main):025:0> bb+cc
=> 500
irb(main):026:0> aa.kind_of? Array
=> true
irb(main):027:0> bb.kind_of? Array
=> false
irb(main):028:0> cc.kind_of? Array
=> false
irb(main):029:0> aa.kind_of? Integer
=> false
irb(main):030:0> bb.kind_of? Integer
=> true
irb(main):031:0> cc.kind_of? Integer
=> true
```

**My questions:**

1. Am I doing any mistake declaring the integer variable this way? Or is it a bug in Ruby?
2. What are the other ways to declare Integer Variable in the same line?

Comment: If in doubt, consult the docs: [multiple assignment](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Multiple+Assignment)

Answer (score 1):

Your example

```
aa = 100, bb = 200, cc = 300
```

is interpreted by Ruby as

```
aa = (100, bb = 200, cc = 300)
```

which a [multiple assignment](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Multiple+Assignment) and is is basically the same as

```
aa = [100, bb = 200, cc = 300]
```

What you need to do is (again using multiple assignment):

```
aa, bb, cc = 100, 200, 300
```

or using this syntax

```
aa = 100; bb = 200; cc = 300
```

that is the same as

```
aa = 100
bb = 200
cc = 300
```

Btw. I would prefer the last version (three lines) because it is the easiest to read and understand version and makes it much easier for other developers in the future to quickly scan what the code does.

Comment: aa, bb, cc = 100, 200, 300 (here individually each is an integer, but as a whole it shows false). and aa = 100; bb = 200; cc = 300 (here both way it shows an integer; according to IRB. 
Btw, thanks for your kind and prompt reply and knowledgeable insights.